# How to point one structure to another

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

I need help pointing `*user_playlist` to a playlist node. How can I do this?

```
struct playlist_ {
  int album;
  int track_num;
  struct playlist_ *next;
};
typedef struct playlist_  playlists;

struct users_ {
  int user_ID;
  playlists *user_playlist;
  struct users_ *next;
};
typedef struct users_ users;

p_users = (users *)malloc(sizeof(users *));
p_users -> user_ID = account_number;
head_users = p_users;
head_users -> next = NULL;
users_pointer = head_users;

p_playlists = (playlists *)malloc(sizeof(playlists));
curr_playlists = p_playlists;
curr_playlists -> album = NULL;
curr_playlists -> track_num = NULL;
curr_playlists -> next = NULL;
curr_users -> user_playlist = curr_playlists;

 users *head_users,*curr_users,*p_users,*users_pointer;
 playlists *head_playlists,*curr_playlists,*p_playlists,*playlist_pointer;
```

Comment: I'm getting Bus Error (core dumped) somewhere

Comment: I think you need to write malloc(sizeof(users)) instead of malloc(sizeof(users*)). 'sizeof(users*)' means size of pointer to 'users', when you need size of 'users'.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet When I run it at gdb I get segmentation Fault right after here `curr_users -> user_playlist = curr_playlists;`

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem:

```
p_users = (users *)malloc(sizeof(users *));
```

it only allocates the size of a pointer, not the size of a `users` structure. Change to:

```
p_users = malloc(sizeof(users));
```

or:

```
p_users = malloc(sizeof(*p_users));
```

[Casting the return value of `malloc()` is unnecessary and potentially dangerous.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

EDIT:

Dereferencing an unitialised, or `NULL`, pointer will cause a segmentation fault. This declares **but does not initialise** `curr_users` (same for other variables listed):

```
users *head_users,*curr_users,*p_users,*users_pointer;
```

An attempt is then made to access `curr_users`:

```
curr_users->user_playlist = curr_playlists; /* Segmentation fault. */
```

Initialise `curr_users` before using, to either a valid `users` structure or to `NULL` and check for non-null before deferencing:

```
users *head_users = NULL,*curr_users = NULL,
    *p_users = NULL,*users_pointer = NULL;

if (curr_users)
{
    curr_users->user_playlist = curr_playlists;
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that doing `p_users = malloc(sizeof(*p_users));` would remedy the problem completely.

Comment: I made the changes but still getting a error a Segmentation fault at `curr_users -> user_playlist = curr_playlists;`

Comment: @LearningC, I don't see where `curr_users` is initialised?

Comment: I just added at the end of the question.

Comment: That is just declarations, not initialisations. If `curr_users` is used without modification from that declaration it will cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you. When I g home I'll try it out. Thanks again.